Defining Separate RestAssured.RequestSpecifications for admin/user endpoints
I have a setup where different authentications are present for lets say admins and users...
I had two different Test Classes which each their @BeforeAll setting the RequestSpecification for the @Tests in their respecive classes:
Admin

//...

  @BeforeAll
  public static void setupResponseSpecification() {
    requestSpec = new RequestSpecBuilder()
        .setBaseUri("https://admin.test.mysite.com")
        .setAccept("application/json")
        .addHeader("X-Client-Id", "admin-test")
        .build();

    responseSpec = new ResponseSpecBuilder()
        //.expectStatusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK)
        .expectResponseTime(Matchers.lessThan(5L), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .expectContentType(ContentType.JSON)
        .build();

    RestAssured.requestSpecification = requestSpec;
    RestAssured.responseSpecification = responseSpec;
  }

//...


User

//...

  @BeforeAll
  public static void setupResponseSpecification() {
    requestSpec = new RequestSpecBuilder()
        .setBaseUri("https://user.test.mysite.com")
        .setAccept("application/json")
        .addHeader("X-Client-Id", "user-test")
        .build();

    responseSpec = new ResponseSpecBuilder()
        //.expectStatusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK)
        .expectResponseTime(Matchers.lessThan(5L), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .expectContentType(ContentType.JSON)
        .build();

    RestAssured.requestSpecification = requestSpec;
    RestAssured.responseSpecification = responseSpec;
  }

//...


I kept getting 401 errors on one of the classes, but it worked when I uncommented the whole of the opposite class, leading me to the conclusion that the line RestAssured.requestSpecification = requestSpec; which was run last, was the one to be active for both.
Is it possible to define two Spec templates and set the appropriate one for each test?

requestSpecification and responseSpecification are static fields of RestAssured class. This is why you cannot have them different in case your tests are parallel.
Having requestSpec saved in your @BeforeAll you can use it in your test with the construction like:
RestAssured
        .given(requestSpec)
        .get()
        .then()
        .spec(responseSpec);

